# Scrapy: Can't strip unicode from my item data (price)

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm building a **scraper** to get the product prices from a website.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for tank in response.xpath('//html/body/div/div[4]/div/div/div/table[1]/tr/td/div/span/span'):
        item = VapeItem()
        item["price"] = tank.xpath("text()").extract()
        yield item
```

And here is the json output:

```
{"price": ["5,00 \u20ac\n  \n    \n  \n  \n  \n      *\n    \n  \n  \n    "]},
```

I've tried encoding("utf-8"), strip, replaces, but nothing seems to work.

My question is: How do I make that output readable. Either make "5.00 €" ( \u20ac) or just "5.00"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Woops..right. My question is: How do I make that output readable. Either make "5.00 €" ( \u20ac) or just "5.00"

Comment: then answer is: your output is already readable, `\u20ac` is == `€`. You are seeing its unicode representation, but if you do `print item['price'][0]` you'll see it is there.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way may be to split once and replace any comma with a decimal:

```
item["price"] = tank.xpath("text()").extract()[0].split(None,1)[0].replace(",",".")
```

That will leave you with `5.00`. Because you have a `*` in the string strip would not work, you could pass that character to strip i,e `[0].rstrip("\n* ")` but if there were other errant chars that would break.

If you want the euro sign too, you can `decode('unicode-escape')`:

```
d={"price": ["5,00 \u20ac\n  \n    \n  \n  \n  \n      *\n    \n  \n  \n    "]}

d["price"] = d["price"][0].decode('unicode-escape').rstrip("\n * ").replace(",",".")

print(d["price"])
5.00 €
```

If you want to combine it with split and keep the sign, also formatting it a bit nicer:

```
p,s,_ = d["price"][0].split(None, 2)

d["price"] = u"{}{}".format(s.decode("unicode_escape"),p.replace(",","."))

print(d["price"])
```

Which will give you:

```
€5.00
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly! I'm still learning python and its the first time I've seen split(None,1).

Comment: @Demandar, just means split on any whitespace once, we just want the first item before the first whitespace so not point splitting the whole string. If you wanted to use the split approach and keep the sign you can `split(None,2)`

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Shouldn't replace("\n", "") work as well?

Comment: @Demandar, that would only replace the newlines not the spaces and the random `*`

Comment: Right! I've tried chaining 3 replaces (I know, its awful code :p) but it didn't replace anything.